# Why does EF drop and create the same index?

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have an existing index (IX_ItemImportSummaryId) which was generated from the ForeignKey on `ItemImportSummary` because that is the default index naming structure. If I try to then explicitly create an index with the same name on the Id field, it will drop the index and then create it again in the migration script.

The funny thing is, if I give it a non-default name instead, it will simply rename the index rather than drop then create it. It almost seems like EF is stupid in this scenario and doesn't realize that it can just not do anything at all.

```
public class ItemImportSummaryDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ItemImportSummaryId")]
    public virtual ItemImportSummary ItemImportSummary { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_ItemImportSummaryId", IsUnique = false)]
    [Index("IX_Mpbid", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public int ItemImportSummaryId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(maximumLength:10)]
    [Index("IX_Mpbid", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public string Mpbid { get; set; }
}
```

This is what add-migration generates:

```
DropIndex("dbo.ItemImportSummaryDetails", new[] { "ItemImportSummaryId" });
CreateIndex("dbo.ItemImportSummaryDetails", "ItemImportSummaryId");
```